# cant insert foreign keys into tables

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-web-developer-2010

im trying to insert foreign keys into table with `DropDownList`,
it looks good but i get this error when i press the add button

> "mysql.data.mysqlclient.mysqlexception {"You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ') values (1,1,1,1)' at line 1"}.

the tables have another Variables but now they dont Important for me and they defaults is null.

i dont have enough reputation to add image with the relationships between the tables.

thanks alot!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class usageDisp : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string connectionstring = @"Data Source=localhost; Database=globaldotdb; user ID=root; Password=peleg1708";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //check
                BindData();

            }
        }
        private void BindData()
        {         
            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(("SELECT  tblusage.codeUsage,tblcustom.Customer, tblvendor.Vendor, tblusage.dateStart, tblusage.dateEnd, tblregion.Region, tblservice.Service, tblservice.unit, tblusage.isSecure,tblusage.Usage FROM     ((((tblvendor INNER JOIN tblusage ON tblvendor.codeVendor = tblusage.codeVendor) INNER JOIN  tblservice ON tblusage.codeService = tblservice.codeService) INNER JOIN  tblregion ON tblusage.codeRegion = tblregion.codeRegion) INNER JOIN  tblcustom ON tblusage.codeCust = tblcustom.codeCust)"), cn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    gv.DataSource = dt;
                    gv.DataBind();



                }
            }
        }

        protected void gv_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            int codeusage = int.Parse(gv.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

            deleteusage(codeusage);
            BindData();
        }

        private void deleteusage(int codeusage)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                string query = "DELETE FROM tblusage WHERE codeUsage=" + codeusage + " ";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }

        protected void gv_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList DDLCu = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLCu") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList DDLVe = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLVe") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList DDLSe = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLSe") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList DDLRe = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLRe") as DropDownList;


            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter Cadp = new MySqlDataAdapter(("SELECT * from tblcustom"), cn);
                DataTable Cdt = new DataTable();
                Cadp.Fill(Cdt);
                if (Cdt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DDLCu.DataSource = Cdt;
                    DDLCu.DataTextField = "Customer";
                    DDLCu.DataValueField = "codeCust";
                    DDLCu.DataBind();

                }


                MySqlDataAdapter Vadp = new MySqlDataAdapter(("SELECT * from tblvendor"), cn);
                DataTable Vdt = new DataTable();
                Vadp.Fill(Vdt);
                if (Vdt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DDLVe.DataSource = Vdt;
                    DDLVe.DataTextField = "Vendor";
                    DDLVe.DataValueField = "codeVendor";
                    DDLVe.DataBind();

                }


                MySqlDataAdapter Sadp = new MySqlDataAdapter(("SELECT * from tblservice"), cn);
                DataTable Sdt = new DataTable();
                Sadp.Fill(Sdt);
                if (Sdt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DDLSe.DataSource = Sdt;
                    DDLSe.DataTextField = "Service";
                    DDLSe.DataValueField = "codeService";
                    DDLSe.DataBind();

                }


                MySqlDataAdapter Radp = new MySqlDataAdapter(("SELECT * from tblregion"), cn);
                DataTable Rdt = new DataTable();
                Radp.Fill(Rdt);
                if (Rdt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DDLRe.DataSource = Rdt;
                    DDLRe.DataTextField = "Region";
                    DDLRe.DataValueField = "codeRegion";
                    DDLRe.DataBind();

                }
            }

        }

        protected void lnkAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList DDLCu = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLCu") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList DDLVe = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLVe") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList DDLSe = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLSe") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList DDLRe = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("DDLRe") as DropDownList;
            int cc = int.Parse(DDLCu.SelectedValue);
            int cv = int.Parse(DDLVe.SelectedValue);
            int cs = int.Parse(DDLSe.SelectedValue);
            int cr = int.Parse(DDLRe.SelectedValue);
            add(cc, cv, cs, cr );
            BindData();
            Response.Redirect("http://localhost:56717/usage.aspx");

        }

        private void add(int cc, int cv,  int cs, int cr)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {

                string query = "insert into tblusage(codeCust,codeVendor,codeService,codeRegion,) values (" + cc + "," + cv +"," + cs + "," + cr  + ") ";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }




    }
}



<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" 
    DataKeyNames="codeUsage" 
        onrowdeleting="gv_RowDeleting" 
         AutoGenerateColumns="False" ondatabound="gv_DataBound" ShowFooter="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="codeusage" Visible="False">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtcode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("codeUsage") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("codeUsage") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTCust" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Customer") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCu" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Customer") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Vendor") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLVe" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Vendor") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="dateStart">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTDS" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dateStart") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dateStart") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="dateEnd">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTDE" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dateEnd") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dateEnd") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="service">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTSe" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Service") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLSe" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Service") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="region">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTRe" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Region") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLRe" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Region") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="isSecure">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTIS" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("isSecure") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("isSecure") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="unit">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTunit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("unit") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("unit") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="usage">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTusage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Usage") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAdd" runat="server" onclick="lnkAdd_Click">add</asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Usage") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Operation" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you post, just the code/SQL that is causing the error rather than this wall of code?

Comment: according to this code, taking that the error is here, insert into tblusage(codeCust,codeVendor,codeService,codeRegion,) values (" + cc + "," + cv +"," + cs + "," + cr  + "), you have an extra comma... .

Comment: This simple typo is just one of the many possibilities of errors that originate from the same wrong behavior. Do not concatenate strings to make sql statements. Use parameterized queries....

Comment: i changed it.
and then this error was showed.
"CS1061: 'ASP.usage_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'gridviewusage_RowUpdating' and no extension method 'gridviewusage_RowUpdating' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.usage_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

i dont know what i need to do.

Comment: why What I have done is wrong? @Steve
i mean after i deleted the extra comma.

Comment: The new error has nothing to do with the command issued to the database. This seems to be something related to your ASPX markup. It seems that you have somewhere a reference to a method gridviewusage_RowUpdating but this method doesn't exist in the code behind file (the .cs). The page involved is the one called 'ASP.usage_aspx' . For the first problem, [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) what could happen with string concatenations.

Comment: i have class that called usage and i copy the code from this class.
but i changed everything and i dont know why it caused this error.
@Steve

Comment: this line Response.Redirect("http://localhost:56717/usage.aspx");
caused the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tblusage(codeCust,codeVendor,codeService,codeRegion`,)`

**errant comma, clobber it**